# How to compare value 3.0.1 with 3.0.2 where these two numeric values are in String?

Tags: java, android

I have 3.0.1 and 3.0.2 in string data type java. Now I want to check which value is larger, therefore I was converting these two into float using `Float.parseFloat(str)`.

But it's throwing a number format exception.

Any Help?

Comment: Well of course. `3.0.1` isn't a decimal number. What did you expect?

Comment: Yup. I want to check with which one is larger value . e.g mobile app version is 3.0.1 and next version is 3.0.2 ... therefore second is larger so I want to do logic based on larger value ?  Any Idea how we can achieve ?

Comment: As @Tunaki said, it is not a decimal number so its obvious that it will throw NFE , what is the reason you want to convert this to float ?

Comment: Because I want to check which one is larger value

Comment: @PravinMohol check my answer

Comment: Too broad. What if the version is `3.0.3-beta-alpha4-RC1-dontusemeplease-M2`?

Comment: @Tunaki I think, he as the developer know his version right.. why can't we help him instead of finding the reasons to close this

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera Because he first need to define what a "version string" is. What about `3.20`? Is it allowed? What about the version in my above comment?

Comment: @PravinMohol You might  have read the comments, please define what version String is

Comment: You can set the period symbol (.) as a separator and parse each integer,  then compare them.

Answer (score 1):

3.0.1 and 3.0.2 are not numbers, they can only be compared as String. That is why you get a number format exception.

Answer (score 1):

Check each number one by one like this

```
public int compare(String x, String y) {
    String[] a = x.split("\\.");
    String[] b = y.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        // Return 1 if x is greater, -1 if y is greater, 0 if equal
        if (Integer.parseInt(a[i]) > Integer.parseInt(b[i])) {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (Integer.parseInt(a[i]) < Integer.parseInt(b[i])) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`3.0.1` is not a number, it is basically a sequence of numbers separated by periods.

One idea is to make a class which represents this version number. We interpret a version code like `3.0.1` as a sequence of numbers separated by periods; basically an array with `int`s. We can just split the input string by the period character, resulting in components of the version number. In a version number, each integer can be called a 'component'. The version number `3.0.1` has three components: `3`, `0` and `1`.

Once we have created two `Version` instances, we can compare them with eachother. The comparison is as follows: for each component the `Version` instance has, that component will be matched against the component at the same position in another version.

```
public class Version implements Comparable<Version> {

    private List<Integer> components = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public Version(String version) {
        String[] parts = version.split("\\.");
        for (String part : parts) {
            // Parse the integer. We assume it is a valid number
            this.components.add(Integer.parseInt(part));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Version o) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.components.size(); i++) {
            // Compare the corresponding elements with eachother.
            // We assume the lengths of the 'numbers' are equal.
            int compare = this.components.get(i).compareTo(o.components.get(i));
            if (compare != 0) {
                return compare;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```